# Windows 2003 Server Crash - Now on 2008 - MySQL IBData1 File Shows Default Tables Only

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I've looked all through the site and haven't found an answer to this question, so I'll ask. I apologize if it is somewhere in here.

I had a MySQL 5.5.15 server running on an old Windows 2003 server. That server finally failed due to hard drive and motherboard issues. I now have a Windows 2008 server. I made sure to put MySQL 5.5.15 on it, so I had matching software for the first step.

I moved over all the data files I had. So this includes the my.ini, the ibdata1 and two log files, a group of mysql-bin files with dates from last December. I couldn't find the .frm files.

I then launched mysqld --console and it started up fine. No errors.

I then launched mysql separately, and asked to see the databases. All it reported were the three default ones - information_schema, mysql, and performance_schema. When I ask about users, it has the default ones. My ibdata1 file is 641mb.

I did try launching it with various values for innodb_force_recovery - with no change. It still starts smoothly, and it still shows just that data in it.

UPDATE 9/13/2013 -
It turns out my system had gotten fairly confused during my upgrade last fall from 5.1 to 5.5. Even though the ini file clearly said to put the data into one spot, there must have been a registry entry or something else still pointing to 5.1. So while the three main files – IBDATA1 and such – were in the 5.5 directory, all the matching .frm files were down in the 5.1 directory.

When I assembled all the pieces together on my 2003 server, with the matching 5.5 MySQL software, POOF, the WordPress five databases exported completely smoothly, with all data up through the crash. Those five databases are up and running on the new server. Everything is fine with them. These five had only .frm files in their directories and were listed in there as INNODB. So the data was indeed in the IBDATA1 file I had.

That leaves the three remaining UBB forum databases. They have .frm as well as .myi and .myd files in the directories. The .frm files indicate that the tables are MYISAM. I had converted them all to INNODB just after the upgrade. So it seems that these .frm files are not the ones that go with the IBDATA1 file. But I can’t find any other .frm files on the old C drive. I was able to successfully export the data that was there in those .myi / .myd files – which was the data state just before I converted them to INNODB, last December. This at least gets the forums live and working with 8 or so years of data – but of course the last 9 months are still missing. Everything after the INNODB conversion is “trapped” in the IBDATA1 file.

I know I converted the tables to INNODB. I know this INNODB file I have (the IBDATA1) was the active one being used, as I just got all the wordpress content out of it. Apparently I now have to find the “correct” .frm files to go with that – or find some way to extract the data from the IBDATA1 file without having the .frm files. Alternately, could I edit the .frm files I do have and change them from saying these tables are MyISAM (their current state) to saying they are INNODB (which in reality they are)?

I'm open to suggestions.

Lisa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I actually need to ask, but are you sure you're putting the files in the correct directory?  The fact that you've replaced the IBData1 file and you've still got the old users after server restart...

As far as I know too, `information_schema` and `performance_schema` are actually views built from non-file sources, so won't be part of the IBData1 file.

Although I have more experience with Linux systems, I know MySQL is fussy about ownership and permissions of the data files.

Also, I would move the log files away from the data dir (while the server is stopped) as the current ones will probably be no use anyway and new ones will be zero-filled on mysql start anyway.

If you've already checked the permissions and ownership, also have a look at if `innodb_file_per_table` is set in your `my.cnf` because if this is the case, your databases will actually live in subfolders of the data directory.  It can be misleading that the IBData1 file is large, but in most versions of MySQL, it won't actually shrink itself after splitting the data up into individual files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. The ibdata1 file and its two log files do get fresh "last modify dates" after I start and stop the MySQL server, so they are being seen and accessed. In my initial testing I did try doing a round where I started it without the two log files, just to see what happened. It gave a mild error, created two fresh log files, and started up. The results were the same. I have the default users, the default databases, and none of my own content.

Comment: I've just updated my answer as it was a bit big for a comment.  This question really belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: Calcinai - As odd as it might sound - it really did make a difference adding those data directories, as far as what MySQL then "thought it had" for available databases. I added the data directories and *poof* the five WordPress blogs were perfectly visible and exportable. It worked fine with the log files there.

Comment: That's great to hear!